# twilio video webrtcc not working on andoird 13 mobile how to resolve?

Tags: react-native

Steps to reproduce
TwilioVideoParticipantView is coming in a black screen when i connect to video call
When the participant joins first and after that I join this issue comes
Expected behaviour
The black screen should not come initially if the participant joins first

Actual behaviour
Their behaviour is inconsitent, when is try to camera on/off.

Environment
**Node.js version:v16.20.1
**React Native version: 0.72.5
React Native platform + platform version: iOS 9.0
react-native-twilio-video-webrtc this is the screenshot of the problem -->(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p6aV.jpg)
**Version: "react-native-twilio-video-webrtc": "^3.2.0

can anyone please help me to figure it out

This is the problem im facing